# Creating a loop that populates a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function buildOrder(data) {
    var $fragment;
    $fragment = $('<div/>');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $fragment.append('<div class="row-container"><div class="row cupcake-row">' + data[i].name + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
    }
    $('#review-section').append($fragment);
}
```

I essentially want to add a  tag with 50 options being dynamically created using a for loop. But I'm not sure what the syntax would be to add it to the `<div class="row-container"/>`  I know in php I would just throw the loop in the middle and echo the options, however that doesnt work in javascript.

EDIT:

It would look like this:

```
$fragment.append('<div class="row-container"><div class="row cupcake-row">' + data[i].name + '</div><select><option value="1">1</option> etc...</select><div class="clear"></div></div>');
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the desired HTML to be generated?  Obviously you don't need to include all 50 options.

Comment: Where does the select tag fit into all this? It's in the question title but your code is all divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a function to `.append` and do your loop there:

```
$("<div>").append(function() {
  var $select = $("<select>");
  for(var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    $("<option>").text(i).val(i).appendTo($select);
  }
  return $select;
});

// returns a jQuery object with one div element (with children):
// <div>
//   <select>
//     <option value="1">1</option>
//     ...
//   </select>
// </div>
```

---

Mixed into your code it would be along the lines of:

```
var $fragment = $("<div>");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var $container = $("<div>").addClass("row-container")
                               .appendTo($fragment);

    $("<div>").addClass("row cupcake-row")
              .text(data[i].name)
              .appendTo($container);

    $("<div>").append(function() {
      var $select = $("<select>");
      for(var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        $("<option>").text(i).val(i).appendTo($select);
      }
      return $select;
    }).appendTo($container);

    $("<div>").addClass("clear")
              .appendTo($container);
}

$("#review-section").append($fragment);
```

Comment: sorry, but how do I get that within my existing tags that im appending to the fragment?

Comment: @Adam: I tried cleaning it up a bit. Without string manipulation this is eaiser, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted code:

```
function buildOrder(data) {
    var $fragment;
    $fragment = '<div><div class="row-container">';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $fragment += '<div class="row cupcake-row">' + data[i].name + '</div><div class="clear"></div>';
    }
    $fragment += '</div></div>';
    $('#review-section').append($fragment);
}
```

But in your posted code doesn't match with your post title, where you mentioned about `select` tag and in your code you're trying with `div`.

If you want to create a `select`, then something like:

```
function buildOrder(data) {
        var $fragment;
        $fragment = '<div class="row-container"><select>'; // taking select within your div
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // adding options to select
            $fragment += '<option value="'+ data[i].name +'">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        $fragment += '</select></div>'; // end select and div
        $('#review-section').append($fragment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function buildOrder(data) {
    var $fragment = $('<div></div>');
    var options = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options.push('<div class="row-container"><div class="row cupcake-row">' + data[i].name + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
    }
    $fragment.html(options.join("\n"));

    $('#review-section').append($fragment);
}
```